# Making a search bar in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a code written using javafx that creates a tableview and then inserts the data given in another file.  Im trying to implement a search bar.  I want to be able to search the table in the gui and have the matches show up. Any direction?

Edit: i understand this question was broad, i wasn't expecting a precise answer, I was just looking for direction.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is really too broad for this forum, which favors precise and specific questions which have definitive answers. I recommend taking the [tour] and looking at the site's [help] in order to post the kinds of questions which contribute to the site. (That said, check out http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/, which is a popular tutorial covering the functionality you are asking about.) See if you can implement what you are looking to do, and post specific questions, with code, if you get stuck.

Comment: I agree with James. Your question is too broad. What I normally do is use a [`ChoiceBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html) and [`TextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html). The `ChoiceBox` allows me to choose what table column I  will be searching. The `TextField` does the search. I also use a [`FilteredList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html) to set the table items.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a sample app I altered from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm).

I altered the app to filter a `TableView` using a `ChoiceBox`, `TextField`, and a `FilteredList`. The `TextField's` `onKeyReleased` does the filtering based on the `ChoiceBox's` current value.

Comments in the code.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewSample extends Application
{

    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                    new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                    new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                    new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                    new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
            );

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(550);

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

        TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));

        FilteredList<Person> flPerson = new FilteredList(data, p -> true);//Pass the data to a filtered list
        table.setItems(flPerson);//Set the table's items using the filtered list
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

        //Adding ChoiceBox and TextField here!
        ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox();
        choiceBox.getItems().addAll("First Name", "Last Name", "Email");
        choiceBox.setValue("First Name");

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setPromptText("Search here!");
        textField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            switch (choiceBox.getValue())//Switch on choiceBox value
            {
                case "First Name":
                    flPerson.setPredicate(p -> p.getFirstName().toLowerCase().contains(newValue.toLowerCase().trim()));//filter table by first name
                    break;
                case "Last Name":
                    flPerson.setPredicate(p -> p.getLastName().toLowerCase().contains(newValue.toLowerCase().trim()));//filter table by last name
                    break;
                case "Email":
                    flPerson.setPredicate(p -> p.getEmail().toLowerCase().contains(newValue.toLowerCase().trim()));//filter table by email
                    break;
            }
        });

        choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal)
                -> {//reset table and textfield when new choice is selected
            if (newVal != null) {
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });

        HBox hBox = new HBox(choiceBox, textField);//Add choiceBox and textField to hBox
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);//Center HBox
        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, hBox);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person
    {
        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final SimpleStringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email)
        {
            this.firstName.setValue(fName);
            this.lastName.setValue(lName);
            this.email.setValue(email);
        }

        public String getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName)
        {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }
        
        public SimpleStringProperty getFirstNameProperty()
        {
            return firstName;
        }
        
        public String getLastName()
        {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName)
        {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty getLastNameProperty()
        {
            return lastName;
        }
        
        public String getEmail()
        {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName)
        {
            email.set(fName);
        }
        
        public SimpleStringProperty getEmailProperty()
        {
            return email;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Updated on 01/08/2021. It now uses the `TextProperty` instead of a `KeyListener` to set the predicate that filters the results.**

Comment: @kleopatra, what do you suggest?

Comment: @kleopatra, thanks!  I will update the answer when I get a chance.

Comment: just to clarify (typing on mobile is .. ;) - the solution as such (use a filteredList and update its predicate) is fine, it's only the trigger that's wrong: a key handler only catches key events (surprise <g>), not other means to change the text. Which can be seen in your code on the checkbox: you have to explicitly null the predicate along with the text, because the progamatic change of the text has no effect. If you listen to the textProperty you can remove that explicitly reset of the predicate.

Comment: Why is there `table.setEditable(true);`? Is this necessary?

Comment: @Lukas, This code was copied from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F8%2Fjavafx%2Ffxml-tutorial%2F%2F/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm). They were probably demoing something that required the table to be editable. For this case, it is not necessary.

Comment: Here is a better link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#JFXUI271.