# JavaFX: How to search a Tableview on search button click depending on column?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tableview

I have loaded a csv file into a tableview in javafx and am trying to search the table for property based on account numbers, addresses, neighbourhoods, etc. Each Textfield corresponds to a specific search purpose as well as the drop down selector. In my pursuit to solve this all the examples ive found filter actively where as i found like to do it when the search button is pressed. Is there a proper way to show only the searched items in the table and display the information in a text area?

Table Controller:

```
public class FileGUI extends Application  {
    TableView table;
    ObservableList<PropertyData> data;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setTitle("Property Assesments");

        // For Label + table 
        // placed vertically (above one another)
        VBox vb1 = new VBox(20);    // set spacing between these nodes to 10

        // For Label + text field 
        // placed vertically (above one another)
        VBox vb2 = new VBox(20);     // set spacing between these nodes to 5

        // vb1 and vb2 will be placed horizontally 
        HBox hb = new HBox(150);     // set spacing between vb1 and vb2 to 20

        // set the scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(hb, 1000, 1000);


        //Set Text Labels
        Label label1 = new Label("Property Data");
        label1.setFont(new Font("Ariel",15));
        createSimpleTable();

        vb1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        vb1.getChildren().addAll(label1,table);

        Label label2 = new Label("Find Property Assesment");
        label2.setFont(new Font("Ariel", 15));
        label2.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold;");


        Label label3 = new Label("Account Number:");
        label3.setFont(Font.font("Ariel", FontWeight.NORMAL, 12));
        label3.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0));

        TextField tf = new TextField();

        Label label4 = new Label("Address (#suite #house street):");
        label4.setFont(Font.font("Ariel", FontWeight.NORMAL, 12));

        TextField tf2 = new TextField();

        Label label5 = new Label("Neighbourhood:");
        label5.setFont(Font.font("Ariel", FontWeight.NORMAL, 12));

        TextField tf3 = new TextField();

        Label label6 = new Label("Assessment Class:");
        label6.setFont(Font.font("Ariel", FontWeight.NORMAL, 12));

        //Set dropdown menu selection
        MenuButton menuBtn = new MenuButton();
        menuBtn.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 100));
        menuBtn.getItems().setAll(new MenuItem("Residential"), new MenuItem("Non Residential"), new MenuItem("Other Residential"));

        Button search = new Button("Search");
        Button reset = new Button("Reset");
        reset.setTranslateX(70);
        reset.setTranslateY(-37);

        TextArea box = new TextArea();
        box.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 60));

        vb2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        vb2.setSpacing(10);
        vb2.setPadding(new Insets(13, 0, 0, 6));
        vb2.getChildren().addAll(label2, label3, tf, label4, tf2, label5, tf3, label6, menuBtn, search, reset, box);

        EventHandler<ActionEvent> searchAcc = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                String accNumber = tf.getText();

            }
        };

        hb.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
        hb.getChildren().addAll(vb2, vb1);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public void createSimpleTable() {
        table = new TableView();
        //Open file as class object
        InitFile csvFile = new InitFile();

        //Check if pathway provided by user exists, if not return default pathway
        File pathName = csvFile.FileExists();
        try {
            //Read file line by line until EOF into Property data structure array
            ArrayList<PropertyData> houses = csvFile.initializeFile(pathName);
            data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(houses);

            TableColumn acc = new TableColumn("Account");
            acc.setMinWidth(90);
            acc.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("accountNum"));

            TableColumn add = new TableColumn("Address");
            add.setMinWidth(180);
            add.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("houseNum"));
            add.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("suite"));
            add.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("streetName"));

            TableColumn assessedVal = new TableColumn("Assessed Value");
            assessedVal.setMinWidth(120);
            assessedVal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("assessedVal"));

            TableColumn assessClass = new TableColumn("Assessment Class");
            assessClass.setMinWidth(120);
            assessClass.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("assessClass"));

            TableColumn nh = new TableColumn("Neighbourhood");
            nh.setMinWidth(190);
            nh.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("neighbourhood"));

            TableColumn lat = new TableColumn("Latitude");
            lat.setMinWidth(130);
            lat.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("latitude"));

            TableColumn lng = new TableColumn("Longitude");
            lng.setMinWidth(130);
            lng.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("longitude"));


            table.setEditable(false);
            table.setPrefWidth(920);
            table.setPrefHeight(640);
            table.getColumns().addAll(acc, add, assessedVal, assessClass, nh, lat, lng);
            table.setItems(data);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File not Found");
        }  
    }



    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[Image of the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfR7x.jpg)

Comment: Not button dependent, but maybe you can use some of the ideas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47559491/making-a-search-bar-in-javafx/47560767#47560767

Comment: Check this [project](https://github.com/frosch95/SmartCSV.fx)

Comment: [mcve] please .. don't seeyou do anything like searching