# How to filter data in tableview in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

i have a tableview in java fx which displays different types of data such as String and Integer.I want to have a data filter so that it automatically displays the data in table view.How can i achieve this?Currently i am using a function but it is not working.NOTE:"pers" is an object of the class that i am using

```
void SearchUser(){
    FilteredList<Issue> filteredData=new FilteredList<>(Ilist,b->true);
    filterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredData.setPredicate(pers->{
            if(newValue==null||newValue.isEmpty()){
                return true;
            }
            String lowerCaseFilter=newValue.toLowerCase();
            if(pers.getCreator().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter)!=-1){
                return true;
            }
            else if(pers.getIssueTitle().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter)!=-1){
                return true;
            }
            else if(String.valueOf(pers.getIssueNo()).indexOf(lowerCaseFilter)!=-1){
                return true;
            } else if(pers.getStatus().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter)!=-1){
                return true;
            }
            else if(pers.getAssignee().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter)!=-1){
                return true;
            }
            else if(pers.getTime().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter)!=-1){
                return true;
            }
            else if(String.valueOf(pers.getPriority()).indexOf(lowerCaseFilter)!=-1){
                return true;
            }
            else if(pers.getTag().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter)!=-1){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
    SortedList<Issue> sortedData=new SortedList<>(filteredData);
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(IssueTable.comparatorProperty());
    IssueTable.setItems(sortedData);

}
```

Comment: Using `if (pers.getCreator().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter))` would make the code a bit shorter and lighter

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? In other words, in what way is it not working?

Comment: i mean when i type in the textfield there is no change in tableview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47559491/making-a-search-bar-in-javafx/47560767#47560767

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks guys as i figured out the problem

the issue was not with the function itself but the fact that i was running this method before putting any data in to the tableview.Since i did not add any exception handling event,my code was throwing NullPointerError.

Thanks for everyone's help