# (Java FX) TableView access cell contents for searching

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am currently working on implementing a search box, which should search through all rows and columns of a (Filtered)TableView. I want the search box to filter items directly in the table and only show rows where the search-string matches any of the text in any of the currently displayed columns (as a user would expect).

Herein lies my problem: I want to search **the cells content directly, not just the data**.
I can't use toString() for each data object, because toString() and the displayed value may vastly differ (f.e. a boolean is represented as a checkbox with no text, which would not match the search "false", the toString() method however would).
I tried generating an empty cell with the cellValueFactory for each column and filling it with data, but I can't access the updateItem()-Method (it's protected), which generates the cell and according to the docs I shouldn't do that anyway.

Other than implementing a cell, which makes updateItem() public (which probably shouldn't be done), or storing all the converters manually (which is tedious and time consuming, because there are a lot of different Entities), do you know of any better solution for searching in a tableView?

Comment: JavaFX components support observable properties. You can provide data to your table via ObservableList. Then do your filtering logic on ObservableList. The TableView will update itself accordingly.

Comment: You should have a model class that you're using as the item type of your table. Each column would then display one property from that model class, or possibly a value derived from those properties. Then you should have the `items` property of the table set to a `FilteredList`. When the search box updates, set a new filter on the `FilteredList` and the table will update automatically.

Comment: *”I want to search the cells content directly, not just the data”*. This doesn’t really make sense. Cells are only created for the visible portion of the data. If you used these for filtering, your filtering would not be able to consider data scrolled out of view, for example.

Comment: It might help to create a [mre] demonstrating the issue. Just a small application with a table with one or two columns, and indicate where the scalability problem (the *"which is tedious and time consuming ..."* part) lies.

Comment: You mention *"a boolean is represented as a checkbox with no text, which would not match the search "false", the toString() method however would)"* -> I suggest creating a question (with the requested [mcve]), which demonstrates just the problem and making it clear what the requirements for that problem are.  For example, would the match to "false" be case insensitive, how would "Y" or "N" values be handled, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking, but it seems you want to filter a table view by the text actually displayed in the cells, without replicating code between the filter and the cell. There seems to be some concern that factoring this out into some external representation is not scalable:

> storing all the converters manually (which is tedious and time consuming, because there are a lot of different Entities)

I dispute this assertion: the "converter" is just a function from the property type to a `String` which can be succinctly expressed as either a lambda expression or a method reference. Given you need to specify this at least once for each property no matter what you do, there seems to be no scalability issue to reuse this.

For example, given a model class for your table data which I'll call `Friend` (shown later), you can define

```
private record ColumnSpec<T>(String title, Function<Friend, ObservableValue<T>> property, Function<T, String> formatter) {}
```

and create a list of these, one for each column:

```
    List<ColumnSpec<?>> columns = List.of(
            new ColumnSpec<>("First Name", Friend::firstNameProperty, Function.identity()),
            new ColumnSpec<>("Last Name", Friend::lastNameProperty, Function.identity()),
            new ColumnSpec<>( "Email", Friend::emailProperty, String::toLowerCase),
            new ColumnSpec<>("Birthday", Friend::birthdayProperty, formatter::format)
    );
```

Then you can easily create filtering which reference these:

```
private <T> boolean match(Friend friend, ColumnSpec<T> column, String searchText) {
    T propertyValue = column.property().apply(friend).getValue();
    String formattedValue = column.formatter().apply(propertyValue);
    return formattedValue.contains(searchText);
}
```

with, for example,

```
    ObservableList<Friend> allFriends = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    FilteredList<Friend> filteredFriends = allFriends.filtered(f -> true);
    table.setItems(filteredFriends);

    TextField searchField = new TextField();
    searchField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldSearch, newSearch) -> {
        String search = newSearch.trim();
        if (search.isBlank()) {
            filteredFriends.setPredicate(friend -> true);
        } else {
            filteredFriends.setPredicate(friend -> {
                for (ColumnSpec<?> column : columns) {
                    if (match(friend, column, search)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
```

and you can additionally create the columns from them:

```
private <T> TableColumn<Friend, T> createColumn(ColumnSpec<T> col) {
    TableColumn<Friend, T> column = new TableColumn<>(col.title());
    column.setCellValueFactory(data -> col.property().apply(data.getValue()));
    column.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText("");
            } else {
                setText(col.formatter().apply(item));
            }
        }
    });
    return column;
}
```

with

```
    for (ColumnSpec<?> column : columns) {
        table.getColumns().add(createColumn(column));
    }
```

The chunk of code that begins `List<ColumnSpec> columns =` has `O(n)` lines of code (each being pretty succinct) for `n` columns, and the remaining code is identical no matter how many columns you have.

Here is a complete example, which is just a minor adaptation of [another answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77580029/2189127):

```
package org.jamesd.examples.tabledemo;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Friend {
    private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthday = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public Friend(String firstName, String lastName, String email, LocalDate birthday) {
        setFirstName(firstName);
        setLastName(lastName);
        setEmail(email);
        setBirthday(birthday);
    }

    public final String getFirstName() {
        return firstNameProperty().get();
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public final void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
    }

    public final String getLastName() {
        return lastNameProperty().get();
    }

    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public final void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
    }

    public final LocalDate getBirthday() {
        return birthdayProperty().get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthdayProperty() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public final void setBirthday(LocalDate birthday) {
        this.birthdayProperty().set(birthday);
    }

    public final String getEmail() {
        return emailProperty().get();
    }

    public StringProperty emailProperty() {
        return email;
    }

    public final void setEmail(String email) {
        this.emailProperty().set(email);
    }
}
```

```
package org.jamesd.examples.tabledemo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    private record ColumnSpec<T>(String title, Function<Friend, ObservableValue<T>> property, Function<T, String> formatter) {}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd");
        List<ColumnSpec> columns = List.of(
                new ColumnSpec<>("First Name", Friend::firstNameProperty, Function.identity()),
                new ColumnSpec<>("Last Name", Friend::lastNameProperty, Function.identity()),
                new ColumnSpec<>( "Email", Friend::emailProperty, String::toLowerCase),
                new ColumnSpec<>("Birthday", Friend::birthdayProperty, formatter::format)
        );

        TableView<Friend> table = new TableView<>();
        ObservableList<Friend> allFriends = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        FilteredList<Friend> filteredFriends = allFriends.filtered(f -> true);
        table.setItems(filteredFriends);

        TextField searchField = new TextField();
        searchField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldSearch, newSearch) -> {
            String search = newSearch.trim();
            if (search.isBlank()) {
                filteredFriends.setPredicate(friend -> true);
            } else {
                filteredFriends.setPredicate(friend -> {
                    for (ColumnSpec<?> column : columns) {
                        if (match(friend, column, search)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            }
        });

        for (ColumnSpec<?> column : columns) {
            table.getColumns().add(createColumn(column));
        }

        allFriends.setAll(
                new Friend("Jane", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com", LocalDate.of(2001, 5, 30)),
                new Friend("Isabella", "Jane", "isabella.johnson@example.com", LocalDate.of(2003, 3, 25)),
                new Friend("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.Jane@example.com", LocalDate.of(1995, 3, 25)),
                new Friend("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com", LocalDate.of(2005, 5, 3)),
                new Friend("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com", LocalDate.of(1998, 10, 5))
        );

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        root.setTop(searchField);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(searchField, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(searchField, new Insets(5));
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private <T> boolean match(Friend friend, ColumnSpec<T> column, String searchText) {
        T propertyValue = column.property().apply(friend).getValue();
        String formattedValue = column.formatter().apply(propertyValue);
        return formattedValue.contains(searchText);
    }

    private <T> TableColumn<Friend, T> createColumn(ColumnSpec<T> col) {
        TableColumn<Friend, T> column = new TableColumn<>(col.title());
        column.setCellValueFactory(data -> col.property().apply(data.getValue()));
        column.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty || item == null) {
                    setText("");
                } else {
                    setText(col.formatter().apply(item));
                }
            }
        });
        return column;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed what I was asking and it seems to be the best way to solve my problem. And you are right: It is just tedious to refactor all the columns that are already implemented, not ones added in the future.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you need to use `OR`/`||` in your filter. It's hard to know given that you posted zero code.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application
{

    private final TableView<Person> table = new TableView();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                                                    new Person("Jane", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                                                    new Person("Isabella", "Jane", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                                                    new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.Jane@example.com"),
                                                    new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                                                    new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
                                                );

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(550);

        Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

        TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));

        FilteredList<Person> flPerson = new FilteredList(data, p -> true);//Pass the data to a filtered list
        table.setItems(flPerson);//Set the table's items using the filtered list
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setPromptText("Search here!");
        textField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            flPerson.setPredicate((p) -> {
                return p.getFirstName().toLowerCase().contains(newValue.toLowerCase().trim()) || 
                p.getLastName().toLowerCase().contains(newValue.toLowerCase().trim()) ||
                p.getEmail().toLowerCase().contains(newValue.toLowerCase().trim());           
            });
        });
            
        final VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setSpacing(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        root.getChildren().addAll(label, table, textField);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
                
    public static class Person
    {
        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final SimpleStringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email)
        {
            this.firstName.setValue(fName);
            this.lastName.setValue(lName);
            this.email.setValue(email);
        }

        public String getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName)
        {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }
        
        public SimpleStringProperty getFirstNameProperty()
        {
            return firstName;
        }
        
        public String getLastName()
        {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName)
        {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty getLastNameProperty()
        {
            return lastName;
        }
        
        public String getEmail()
        {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName)
        {
            email.set(fName);
        }
        
        public SimpleStringProperty getEmailProperty()
        {
            return email;
        }
    }
}
```

Altered code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47560767/2423906

**Output**

[image]